# Threadpool connections in Oracle

Tags: oracle, c#-4.0, threadpool

I tried to open an oracle connection in a method that is being called by:

`ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback())`.

But when another thread (let's say thread 2) starts just after a connection is opened in thread1, this thread1 is being closed without actually performing my task by throwing connection timed out exception.

Can I not open individual connections for each thread with the same connection String?

```
static void LongRunningProcess(object threadId) 
{
  Int32 k = Thread.CurrentThread.GetHashCode(); 

  if (p[k].Equals(0)) 
  {
       p[k] = k; 
       con1[k] = new OracleConnection("data source=TAPTI; user id=PROV582; password=PROV582"); 
       Console.WriteLine("New Connection {0} ", k); 
       con1[k].Open();

        //getting exception here 
  } 

  ProvsionRequestVO valobj = new ProvsionRequestVO(); 
  valobj = ProvsionRequestVO)q.Dequeue(); 
  try { 
       // my logic 
  }
```

the above is the metod being invoked by ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem

Comment: Sure you can, it's probably some issue with your code, i.e. perhaps the threads are accessing the same memory, some code would help identify the problem

Comment: static void LongRunningProcess(object threadId)
        {Int32 k = Thread.CurrentThread.GetHashCode();
            if (p[k].Equals(0))
            {p[k] = k;
             con1[k] = new OracleConnection("data source=TAPTI;  user id=PROV582; password=PROV582");
                Console.WriteLine("New Connection {0} ", k);
                con1[k].Open();//getting exception here
           }
         ProvsionRequestVO valobj = new ProvsionRequestVO();
            valobj = (ProvsionRequestVO)q.Dequeue();
            try
            {
               // my logic

            }

Comment: the above is the metod being invoked by ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem

Answer (score 0):

My guess is your p[] or con1[] array are shared between the threads and possibly being corrupted. Just to verify that 2 connections work, try this code

```
static void LongRunningProcess(object threadId) 
{
    OracleConnection con = new OracleConnection("data source=TAPTI; user id=PROV582; password=PROV582"); 
    Console.WriteLine("New Connection {0} ", Thread.CurrentThread.GetHashCode()); 
    con.Open();

    ProvsionRequestVO valobj = new ProvsionRequestVO(); 
    valobj = ProvsionRequestVO)q.Dequeue(); 

    try { 
        // my logic using con instead
    }
}
```

Make sure close close and dispose con at the end of this method

Comment: But I require an individual connection for each thread to speed up my process. Will the above code serve my purpose?

Comment: If you use threadpool it is, see this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3665981/oracleconnection-lifetime-best-practises